# Interface for enum with nested types

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an enum and i need to define interface for the state using the enum as a key and object as a value: 
How can I describe the enum a key type

```js
export enum Language {
  CS,
  EN
}

const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState<IUserInput>({
    [Language.EN]: {
      title: '',
      price: '',
      additional_info: '',
      content: ''
    },

interface IUserInput {
    // ?
}
```

Comment: Did I understand correctly. You want `IUserInput` to contain properties with key's of type `Language` and values of `Object`?

Comment: yes, sorry I am new to ts so probably my terminology is a bit wrong

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the computed property syntax:

```
interface IUserInput {
    [Language.EN]: {
       title: string,
       price: string,
       additional_info: string,
       content: string
    },
}
```

Or if you want to map over all the keys in the enum you can use the `Record` mapped type

```
type IUserInput = Record<Language, {
    title: string,
    price: string,
    additional_info: string,
    content: string
}>
```